# XML Response to Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, xmlhttprequest, linq-to-xml

**My XML response looks like this:**

```
"<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<HotelAvailResponse xmlns="http://www.juniper.es/webservice/2007/">
<AvailabilityRS Url="http://xml.bookingengine.es"
TimeStamp="20130327T14:38:54.6916528+01:00"
IntCode="lCf65bPrG+x7VDLB0IquVNQgKloRA9+HOuhfHMj0BcE=">
<Results>
<HotelResult Code="7b0LYEzfsd0HH90sd" JPCode="JP003600" DestinationZone="39303" JPDCode="JPD000014">
<HotelInfo>
<Name>Hotel Test</Name>
<Description>A spacious, quiet, light and bright hotel, with a garden and fabulous views across the city.</Description>
<Images>
<Image>http://www.bookingengine.es/images/upload_p/hoteltest.jpeg</Image>
</Images>
<HotelCategory>1 1/2 Stars</HotelCategory>
<HotelType Type="SKI">Snow</HotelType>
<Address>c/tap</Address>
</HotelInfo>
<HotelOptions>
<HotelOption RatePlanCode="dcFZbKty1cJGKeRtgxIDGUZAprp1mua8ySl4iVIZ7NVKBF/PGk8lhZlN7Hcszjs2RwUR2Dxsrv5l0cZDORKz6frEmPdibqOyV2Jg4Dxz8/bF5gqPyQR8+z1LEu8LCVlS" Status="OK">
<Board Type="AD">Bed&amp;Breakfast</Board>
<Prices>
<Price Type="S" Currency="USD">
<TotalFixAmounts Gross="353.65" Nett="353.65">
<Service Amount="321.5"/>
<ServiceTaxes Included="true" Amount="32.15"/>
<Commissions Included="true" Amount="0"/>
<HandlingFees Included="true" Amount="0"/>
<Discount Amount="-0"/>
</TotalFixAmounts>
</Price>
</Prices>
<HotelRooms>
<HotelRoom Units="1" Source="1" AvailRooms="12">
<Name>Double Room</Name>
<RoomCategory Type="DBL">Double Standard</RoomCategory>
</HotelRoom>
<HotelRoom Units="1" Source="2" AvailRooms="45">
<Name>Single</Name>
<RoomCategory Type="SGL">Single Standard</RoomCategory>
</HotelRoom>
</HotelRooms>
</HotelOption>
<HotelOption RatePlanCode="dcFZbKty1cJGKeRtgxIDGUZAprp1mua8ySl4iVIZ7NVKBF/PGk8lhZlN7Hcszjs2RwUR2Dxsrv5l0cZDORKz6frEmPdibqOyV2Jg4Dxz8/bmoX041DU9+3D3nHCEB/6vYKbVtJR2qaHwW9VnnWl/KA==" Status="OK">
<Board Type="AD">Bed&amp;Breakfast</Board>
<Prices>
<Price Type="S" Currency="USD">
<TotalFixAmounts Gross="353.65" Nett="353.65">
<Service Amount="321.5"/>
<ServiceTaxes Included="true" Amount="32.15"/>
<Commissions Included="true" Amount="0"/>
<HandlingFees Included="true" Amount="0"/>
<Discount Amount="-0"/>
</TotalFixAmounts>
</Price>
</Prices>
<HotelRooms>
<HotelRoom Units="1" Source="1" AvailRooms="12">
<Name>Double Room</Name>
<RoomCategory Type="DBL">Double Standard</RoomCategory>
</HotelRoom>
<HotelRoom Units="1" Source="2" AvailRooms="11">
<Name>Double Room</Name>
<RoomCategory Type="DBL">Double Standard</RoomCategory>
</HotelRoom>
</HotelRooms>
<AdditionalElements>
<HotelOffers>
<HotelOffer>
<Name>Basic Discount 10%</Name>
</HotelOffer>
</HotelOffers>
</AdditionalElements>
</HotelOption>
</HotelOptions>
</HotelResult>
</Results>
</AvailabilityRS>
</HotelAvailResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>"
```

**And i have this Linq for that response is as follows:**

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
var hotels = (from hotelData in data.Descendants(ns + "Envelope").Descendants(ns + "Body").Descendants("HotelAvailResponse").Descendants("HotelAvailResult").Descendants("Results").Descendants("HotelResult")

                      select new Hotel
                          {
                              Code = hotelData.Attribute("Code").Value,
                              JpCode =
                                  hotelData.Attributes().Any(x => x.Name == "JPCode")
                                      ? hotelData.Attribute("JPCode").Value
                                      : "",
                              DestinationZone =
                                  hotelData.Attribute("DestinationZone") != null
                                      ? hotelData.Attribute("DestinationZone").Value
                                      : string.Empty,
                              JpdCode = hotelData.Attribute("JPDCode").Value,
                              //HotelName = Convert.ToString(hotelData.Element("Item").Value),
                              //Rating = Convert.ToInt32(hotelData.Element("StarRating").Value),

                              HotelInfo = (from hi in hotelData.Descendants("HotelInfo")
                              select new HotelInfo
                                  {
                                      Name = hi.Element("Name").Value,
                                      Description = hi.Element("Description").Value,
                                      Image = (from img in hi.Descendants("Images") select new Imagez { Images = img.Element("Image").Value }).ToList(),
                                      HotelCategory = hi.Element("Name").Value,
                                      HotelType = hi.Element("Description").Value,
                                      Address = hi.Element("Description").Value,
                                  }
                                  ).ToList(),

                              HotelOptions = (from ho in hotelData.Descendants("HotelOptions")
                                                  select new HotelOptions()
                                                      {
                                                          HotelOption = ho.Element("HotelOption").Attribute("RatePlanCode").Value,
                                                          Board = ho.Element("Board").Attribute("Type").Value,
                                                          Prices = (from pr in ho.Descendants("Prices") select new Prices() { Price = pr.Element("Price").Value,
                                                          TotalFixAmounts = (from tfa in pr.Descendants("TotalFixAmounts") select new TotalFixAmounts() 
                                                          { Service = tfa.Element("Service").Attribute("Amount").Value,
                                                            ServiceTaxes = tfa.Element("ServiceTaxes").Attribute("Included").Value,
                                                            AmountServiceTaxes = tfa.Element("ServiceTaxes").Attribute("Amount").Value,
                                                            Commissions = tfa.Element("Commissions").Attribute("Included").Value,
                                                            AmountCommissions = tfa.Element("Commissions").Attribute("Amount").Value,
                                                            HandlingFees = tfa.Element("HandlingFees").Attribute("Included").Value,
                                                            AmountHandlingFees = tfa.Element("HandlingFees").Attribute("Amount").Value,
                                                            Discount = tfa.Element("Amount").Attribute("Included").Value,
                                                          }).ToList(),
                                                          }).ToList(),
                                                      }).ToList(),
                          }).ToList();
        return hotels;
```

I get no error and neither any exception but the count for hotels returned is 0.
I am a beginner at Linq.
Any help will be much appreciated, and its been 7 hours straight, I am searching for help and trying to get it done. Now I feel the dead end.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your posted code.

The first issue is that the code does not account for the namespace assigned to `<HotelResult>`.  The namespace is http://wwww.juniper.es/webservice/2007/, and is inherited from the `<HotelAvailResponse>` element.  You can see the namespace as an `xmlns` attribute:

```
<HotelAvailResponse xmlns="http://www.juniper.es/webservice/2007/">
```

This is the reason your LINQ query is not returning anything - it's looking for `<HotelAvailResponse>` with the XML Namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope, and that node does not exist, so you get an empty collection.  Each time there is a call to `Descendants` or `Element`, the namespace needs to be included (i.e., `ns + "ElementName"`).

The second issue isn't readily apparent until the code acutally runs, but the following statement

```
HotelOptions = (from ho in hotelData.Descendants(ns + "HotelOption")
```

will result in `<HotelOption>` and `<Board>` appearing only once (i.e., a list of 1) rather than twice.  The `<price>` information and `<TotalFixAmounts>` populates correctly - I'm not entirely sure why, but it may have to do with the nested list for `<TotalFixAmounts>`.  This is easily fixed by changing the select to `<HotelOption>`, like this:

```
HotelOption = (from ho in hotelData.Descendants("HotelOption")
```

Now `ho` will be a collection of `<HotelOption>` nodes and their children, both will be processed and the nested list will be processed as well.

Next there are a couple of problems with your LINQ statement that will throw null reference exceptions (assuming the namespace issue is corrected).  These are:

```
Board = ho.Element("Board").Attribute("Type").Value;
```

`ho` is the collection of all the `<HotelOptions>` nodes and their children - but `<Board>` is a child of `<HotelOption>`, which in itself is a child of `<HotelOptions>`.  When working with XML, remember it's hierarchical in nature - `.Element(elementName)` will access the **first** element with that name that is a child (not a grand child or farther down) of the parent element.  A fairly simple solution is to add `<HotelOption>` into the statement:

```
Board = ho.Element(ns + "HotelOption").Element(ns + "Board").Attribute("Type").Value;
```

A similar issue occurs here:

```
TotalFixAmounts = (from tfa in pr.Descendants("Prices") select new
```

`pr` is the collection of `<Prices>` nodes, but the elements being referenced in the `select` statement are children of `<Price>`, not `<Prices>`.  `Element(elementName)` will get the **first** child node of the parent element, and `<Prices>` does not have any children other than `<Price>`.

Finally, there is no `<Amount>` element that is a child of `<TotalFixAmounts>`, so the following line will also throw a null reference exception:

```
Discount = tfa.Element("Amount").Attribute("Included").Value;
```

In place of the two ternary operators you use, I would recommend using `(string)` - the explicit cast will safely handle missing elements or attributes.  If the element or attribute is missing, the code will not fail, it will simply have no value for that property.

So, putting this all together you get this:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.juniper.es/webservice/2007/";

var hotels = (from hotelData in data.Root.Descendants(ns + "HotelResult")
              select new Hotel
              {
                  Code = (string)hotelData.Attribute("Code"),
                  JpCode = (string)hotelData.Attribute("JPCode"),
                  DestinationZone = (string)hotelData.Attribute("DestinationZone"),
                  JpdCode = (string)hotelData.Attribute("JPDCode"),
                  HotelInfo = (from hi in hotelData.Descendants(ns + "HotelInfo")
                               select new HotelInfo
                               {
                                   Name = (string)hi.Element("Name"),
                                   Description = (string)hi.Element(ns + "Description"),
                                   Image = (from img in hi.Descendants(ns + "Images")
                                            select new Imagez
                                            {
                                                Images = (string)img.Element(ns + "Image")
                                            }).ToList(),
                                   HotelCategory = (string)hi.Element(ns + "Name"),
                                   HotelType = (string)hi.Element(ns + "Description"),
                                   Address = (string)hi.Element(ns + "Description"),
                               }).ToList(),
                  HotelOptions = (from ho in hotelData.Descendants(ns + "HotelOption")
                                  select new HotelOptions
                                  {
                                      HotelOption = ho.Attribute("RatePlanCode").Value,
                                      Board = ho.Element(ns + "Board").Attribute("Type").Value,
                                      Prices = (from pr in ho.Descendants(ns + "Prices")
                                                select new Price
                                                {
                                                    Price = (string)pr.Element(ns + "Price"),
                                                    TotalFixAmounts = (from tfa in pr.Descendants(ns + "Price").Descendants(ns + "TotalFixAmounts")
                                                                       select new TotalFixAmounts
                                                                       {
                                                                           Service = tfa.Element(ns + "Service").Attribute("Amount").Value,
                                                                           ServiceTaxes = tfa.Element(ns + "ServiceTaxes").Attribute("Included").Value,
                                                                           AmountServiceTaxes = tfa.Element(ns + "ServiceTaxes").Attribute("Amount").Value,
                                                                           Commissions = tfa.Element(ns + "Commissions").Attribute("Included").Value,
                                                                           AmountCommissions = tfa.Element(ns + "Commissions").Attribute("Amount").Value,
                                                                           HandlingFees = tfa.Element(ns + "HandlingFees").Attribute("Included").Value,
                                                                           AmountHandlingFees = tfa.Element(ns + "HandlingFees").Attribute("Amount").Value
                                                                       }).ToList(),
                                                }).ToList(),
                                  }).ToList(),
              }).ToList();
```

Note that every reference to `Descendants` or `Element` has the namespace `ns` in it.